# Api Yandex Maps. Закрасить страну

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть поиск по регионам:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/regions.html#regions__each

И песочница:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions/

Но как обратиться не к региону, а к определенной стране, задав для нее background?

Answer (score 2):

Страны мира можно вывести через код `001`, в остальном всё работает точно также.
Вот пример:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

  map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [50, 30],
    zoom: 1,
    controls: ['typeSelector']
  }, {
    typeSelectorSize: 'small'
  });

  ymaps.borders.load('001', {
    lang: 'ru',
    quality: 1
  }).then(function(geojson) {
    var regions = ymaps.geoQuery(geojson);
    regions.search('properties.iso3166 = "RU"').setOptions('fillColor', '#6961b0');
    regions.addToMap(map);
  });

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map">
</div>
```